# Use google plus api to insert activity in page

Tags: python, api, google-plus

I need that from my website admin screen to be able to post to my page stream. Using the `Google Plus API` I want to be able to add activities and share a URL on my page stream. However what is happening is that the post appears on my profile page rather than the page created under this profile. Below is a snippet of my code in Python. Instead of 'me' I tried using the `page_id` but it gives me an error wrong credentials. I would appreciate some help on this as I am stuck and have been trying different things these last 5 days and nothing works.

After `OAuth2` success I do the following:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service_plus = build('plus', 'v1', http=http)
service_plus_domain = build('plusDomains', 'v1', http=http)


activity = {
    'object': {
        'url': 'https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/photo',
    },
    'access': {
       'items': [{
           'type': 'public'
       }],
       'domainRestricted': True
    }
 }

google_request = service_plus_domain.activities().insert(
    userId='me',  #Trying page_id here gives invalid credentials
    body=activity
)

result = google_request.execute()
print result
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I can't help with it but, I am sure that people would like to know the exact error of your wrong credentials.

Comment: Are you sure you've got all of the necessary [scopes](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating) authorized? Have you got an access token for a user who's profile you're trying to post on? You may need to use a [service account flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) to obtain those.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the Plus API nor the Plus Domains API will let you post to a *Page*. The Domains API will only let you post as a *User Profile*, and then only in some limited ways.

To post to a page, you need to either use the [Plus Page API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup) (which is limited to selected partners) or work with one of the partners who have access such as HootSuite.

Comment: Thanks I thought it was limited but I thought I am doing something wrong as the same thing I managed to do it on Facebook.